# Measuring the impact of model parameters

Tags: r, machine-learning, model, prediction

I have model that determines the amount of 'staff' in the shop.
They are 2 parameters: 'average basket' and 'traffic'.
I want to know the percentage influence of both variables to determine the 'staff'. How I can measure it?

I did try:

```
a <- cor(div_staff_target$staff, div_staff_target$div_target)
a = 0.9398103
b <- cor(div_staff_target$staff, div_staff_target$forecasted_traffic)
b = 0.8287353
```

I am not really sure is it correct way.

[data.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qCD2uaL45ZbO0gys1K-gZ7h4E3lBH5K9ath4fwgtbN0/edit#gid=0)

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ Also I can not access your data.

Comment: You state that you have a model... what is it?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233432/measuring-the-impact-of-model-parameters